# How to export two (or more) different series into two (or more) different columns in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel

I have 2 pandas series of different length, I want to export them into 2 different columns. I used concat function but, it is not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNKl6.png)

In this image you can see the code and output. When I export it into excel I got something like below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT5Wk.png)

But, I want all of them in same row with AI90721G1 and AI90721G6, AI90721G10 in different column. Like below : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4hOq.png)

How can I do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Don't post your code as an image. Edit your question and paste it as text instead.